Super User is trialling the new image hosting system
I was informed that we're testing the new image upload system. Practically, other than the URL changing, it appears to be identical.
If there's any issues with image uploads, feel free to post a new post on meta.superuser.com for issue tracking purposes.
While generally moderator coverage on meta is sufficient, and we're told community team members are monitoring the status of the trial
We're keeping this post open for meta discussion - issues like If we need a specific tag for the internal image uploader test and what we call it comes to mind
In addition, we're only human (except the ones that're dogs), so if we might have missed something in relation to this for more than a day or two, or its a urgent issue like everything being broken, feel free to drop a line on Ask a Super User Moderator, and give me a ping, and one of the moderators, or I will try to help with it.

On meta here or SE meta? I saw there was an issue with minimum image sizes reported elsewhere; it seems like that's something our users might run into!

Here. The user had the issue on SF. I'd clarified its the new image upload system, let a community manager behind the scenes so someone could get on it, and its under review. I might not mod meta, but I do still keep an eye on things ;)
